# Word meaning something is technically accurate but overly simplistic

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to think of a word used to describe someone who is intentionally oversimplifying an argument by making a statement that is technically true, but ignores a lot of issues. Its an adjective similar to describing the person as being intentionally obtuse or too clever for their own good.

Comment: Commonly known as the "strawman fallacy".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for "disingenuous?"

Answer (score 3):

Another take on this could be "reductive"?

Comment: Haven't actually heard it used like that before. Similar but doesn't imply that the author is doing it intentionally, which is what I was going for

Answer (score 3):

I might go with "glib" as a synonym for "superficial."  However, neither of those are really about being too clever.

When I think of "too clever," I think of "cocky" of "flip."

Answer (score 0):

**Shallow**, **superficial**, or **facile**:

> From WordNet (r) 3.0 (2006) [wn]:
>
> **facile**
>         *adj* 1: arrived at without due care or effort; lacking depth;
>                *"too facile a solution for so complex a problem"*