# idiom or expression for technically true but ignoring a bigger more important truth

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

What English phrase or idiom expresses this thought:

An argument that refutes an idea is technically correct, but it refutes only a very specific definition, and ignores or sidesteps a more fundamental truth behind the idea that it refutes.

I'm thinking I would be able to find a clever turn of phrase, something along the lines of

"extinguishing the candle and ignoring the forest fire", or

"re-arranging deck chairs on the Titanic"

---

As an example, a contributor to CNN (Max Richtman) says that there is "no truth" in any of the "myths" surrounding Social Security.

"No, no one is stealing from Social Security"

https://www.cnn.com/2018/05/21/opinions/social-security-myths-opinion-richtman/index.html

Richtman claims that there is "no truth" in the "myth" that Social Security funds have been used for other purposes. He claims the one "myth" is based on a "fundamental misunderstanding" of Social Security's finances.

His argument is technically correct... money borrowed from Social Security trust fund were replaced with debt notes. At some point in the (near) future, that money will need to be returned to the trust fund in order to pay benefits to Social Security recipients.

Richtman's argument seemingly ignores the basic idea that money "borrowed" from the trust fund went into the general fund, and was spent on things other than social security benefits.

The bigger reality is that it is no longer possible for the Treasury to borrow more money from the Social Security trust fund, and that the money already borrowed will need to be returned.

The political reality is that Social Security is no longer a source of money to be spent, and is now actually an expenditure out of general revenue.

---

In terms of a logical argument, we might say Richtman is knocking down a strawman of his own invention. But that doesn't feel right. And it's not right to say that he's tilting at windmills.

I don't think Richtman's argument attains the level of *subterfuge* , and I don't think *disingenuous* works. (I don't want to ascribe a motivation to Mr. Richtman.)

My question is: What English expression or idiom conveys the idea that an argument, while technically true, that argument fails to address a much bigger, more fundamental truth?

(I've searched but, to borrow the words from a 1987 hit by U2, "I still haven't found what I'm looking for.")

[Word meaning something is technically accurate but overly simplistic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124742/word-meaning-something-is-technically-accurate-but-overly-simplistic)

[Is there a word for when a statement is technically true but misleading?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224257/is-there-a-word-for-when-a-statement-is-technically-true-but-misleading)

Comment: His point is correct though! Treasury isn't borrowing money from a "depleted Social Security trust fund". Only the excess funds for each year get put into Treasury bonds. Social Security was running surpluses every year until 2010. Here's a [Politifact article that explains how it works](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2015/aug/03/facebook-posts/did-george-w-bush-borrow-social-security-fund-war-/), which is probably more trustworthy than Richtman's article, which is labelled as an opinion, specifically, a political op-ed by CNN.

Comment: If you believe that Richtman is ignoring a larger truth, the word that you provided, _disingenuous_ would be suitable to describe the situation.

Comment: narrow and broad interpretations of arguments. Narrowly construed arguments, broadly construed ones.

Comment: I think the "knocking down a strawman" example you reject is probably the best you'll get for an idiomatic phrase. Some straw men are completely vacuous, as nobody actually believes the straw man's side of an argument. But sometimes the straw man can be a valid, but oversimplified argument, which makes the argument against it not strictly wrong, but weaker than it purports to be.

Comment: Your example is over complex and open to disagreement. It's level of detail is such that we might think you were trying to make a point about the argument than the English definition. Please find an alternate example.

Comment: Are you kidding, or what, please? The “bigger reality” seems to be that you’re attempting to justify something which has no basis in logic or reality.

Could you elaborate on any argument that might refute an idea which is technically correct but refutes only a very specific definition, and ignores or sidesteps a more fundamental truth behind the idea refuted? Can you provide any clarity there?

To me neither "extinguishing the candle and ignoring the forest fire", nor "re-arranging deck chairs on the Titanic" comes anywhere close and neither is either similar to your Richtman myth.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin:  I apologize If I caused confusion. You are right. The examples I gave were just of turns of phrase. Those two phrases carry a different meanings. Those are just example metaphors, and you are right, neither comes close to conveying the idea. Those were intended to illustrate style, not the intended meaning.

Comment: You haven't shown what is so "technically correct" about Mr. Richtman's statement, which I must assume is "No, no one is stealing from Social Security". I'm sure he had a lot more to say, but that statement which you gave in quotes is clearly more of a denial than anything. I'm inclined to suggest that your suspicions concerning "subterfuge" and "disingenuous" are correct, after all. As far as I'm concerned, you've answered your own question.

Comment: Sorry, spencer7593, and if you go back and read what xiota posted, you might notice it has nothing to do with what you thought… 

*Of course* I'm not simply suggesting; I’m begging that you recognise there are no English expressions of that idea. If you think there are, please post three or four…

What you could most usefully do would be first, find an exact expression of that idea in any language then find a translation… remembering first to post the original in whatever language and then post where you got the translation…

Otherwise please, post your own idea…

Comment: People are  obsessed with single words when often single words won't cut it. And that sure gets old fast.

Comment: Sorry, Spencer7593; can you accept that whoever told you that was a common concept expressed in a variety of ways might have been mistaken? Is that possible, or not?

Comment: [Blind men and the elephant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_men_and_an_elephant) . "The parable has been used to illustrate a range of truths and fallacies; broadly, the parable implies that one's subjective experience can be true, but that such experience is inherently limited by its failure to account for other truths or a totality of truth."

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: It seems like you are positing an answer to the question I asked, "There is no English phrase or idiom that expresses that thought." Maybe you would consider posting that as an answer, rather than as a comment. (I know you suggested that I cancel the question. I don't see an option to "cancel",  I could delete it, if the community consensus is that this is NARQ, or is off topic.)

Comment: Thanks for your confidence and trust and have you any idea how much more effort a half-way acceptable Answer takes, than a simple Comment?

Comment: Quite separately, what's NARQ, please?

Comment: Spencer, the point of me asking for another example is so that we know what you mean. If I understood the question well enough to write an example for you I would write an answer.

Comment: @DJClayworth: I apologize for the example. The idea I wanted to express was that a thesis adequately addresses a hyperbole, but "falls short" of addressing a broader issue highlighted by the hyperbole. I want to validate the thesis "as far as it goes", but at the same time, point out that the thesis fails to illuminate the broader issue, the point of the hyberbole, (I don't want to imply that the author of the thesis isn't aware of the broader issue, or that the thesis is deceitful or fallacious.) I don't want to "win a debate", I was just looking for some wording of that idea.

Comment: Spencer  - I think your comments about acknowledging the **as far as it goes**  might actually be your answer.  Also, it might help the question if the Title included "~politely point out that~  ~another persons point~  is  technically true but ..."    I also rather than "don't think" which makes it an assessment of the politics -  declartively tell us(ELU) that you do NOT want to suggest a trick or a ploy or a deception ( where you are not sure about "strawman"  and clear that you do not want to say "disingenuous" etc.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Don't throw the baby out with the bathwater**

> is an idiomatic expression for an avoidable error in which something good is eliminated when trying to get rid of something bad, or in other words, rejecting the favourable along with the unfavourable.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_throw_the_baby_out_with_the_bathwater

Comment: Thanks (@ RobynSimpson). I think this expression may fit the bill.

Comment: I'm glad the OP found what they needed. I still do not feel the answer is correct for the question as stated. I am leaving alone now.

Answer (score 4):

to **miss the point**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/miss+the+point) idiom

> To misunderstand the essence or crux of something; Overlook or fail to understand the essential or important part of something,

Answer (score 3):

A couple of quotes for debating with someone who is twisting facts and statistics.

1)

> **Lies, damned lies, and statistics**
>
> *"Lies, damned lies, and statistics"* is a phrase describing the persuasive power of numbers, particularly the use of statistics to bolster weak arguments. It is also sometimes colloquially used to doubt statistics used to prove an opponent's point.
>
> The term was popularised in United States by Mark Twain (among others), who attributed it to the British Prime Minister Benjamin Disraeli: *"There are three kinds of lies: lies, damned lies, and statistics."*
>   — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lies,_damned_lies,_and_statistics)

2)

> **The devil can cite Scripture for his purpose.**
>
> — Shakespeare's [The Merchant of Venice](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/merchant/merchant.1.3.html)

Answer (score 3):

*this is moved from a comment to an answer as I believe it is different enough*

A common term that questions the relevance of a point is:

#### "red herring" -

> [A red herring (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) is something that misleads or distracts from a relevant or important issue.
>
> It may be either a logical fallacy or a literary device that leads readers or audiences towards a false conclusion.
>
> A red herring might be intentionally used, such as in mystery fiction **or as part of rhetorical strategies (e.g. in politics)**, or it could be inadvertently used during argumentation.
>
> Unlike the straw man, which is premised on a *distortion of the other party's* position, the **red herring is a seemingly plausible, though ultimately irrelevant, diversionary tactic.**
>
> According to the Oxford English Dictionary, a red herring may be intentional, or unintentional; it does not necessarily mean a conscious intent to mislead
>
> **The expression is mainly used to assert that an argument is not relevant to the issue being discussed.** For example, *"I think we should make the academic requirements stricter for students. I recommend you support this because we are in a budget crisis, and we do not want our salaries affected."* The second sentence, though used to support the first sentence, does not address that topic.

Ok - now the question is if "questions the relevance" is close enough to the situation at hand ?

I am not sure, that "fungibility" of dropping IOUs vs the pay as you go is truly 'irrelevant'

yet you might say

> Arguing about whether or not there is a "trust fund" or if government bonds are "assets" is a red-herring argument that distracts us from the bigger point that no matter what you call it , cash to pay benefits for all practical purposes needs to come from taxes or borrowing exactly like any other item in our federal budget.

But, if the goal were more to categorize his 'sneakiness', you might try:

> ### smoke and mirrors
>
> The obscuring or embellishing of the truth of a situation with misleading or irrelevant information.
>
> ***‘the budget process is an exercise in smoke and mirrors’***

so, you could for instance say

> The idea of the social security trust fund is just a smoke and mirrors attempt to distract us from the truth that every check written will come from borrowing or taxes coming into the government, no matter what the source.

Comment: Tom22,  I concur that using "smoke and mirrors" seems to imply a sneaky intention to deceive. I want to avoid that connotation. I think "red herring" would be a better fit for the idea I want to express.  The example wording using both phrases is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

TFD(idioms):

> **[can't see the wood for the trees](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/can%27t+see+the+wood+for+the+trees)**
>
> Cannot see, understand, or focus on a situation in its entirety due to
>   being preoccupied with minor details.
>
> The way he's obsessing over one doorknob when we're renovating the
>   entire house makes me think that he can't see the wood for the trees.
>
> Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights reserved.

Answer (score 2):

While you said in the question that it didn't feel quite right, I think that **straw man** is still the best idiom to describe an argument that defeats only a simplified version of a real problem.

TFD(idioms):

> [**straw man**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/straw+man)
>
> a weak proposition posited only to be demolished by a simple countering argument. *So you can knock down your own straw man! Big deal. The question is how can you deal with real problems.*
>
> McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.

When you use a straw man in an argument, you present a problem or opposing argument in a way that is easier for you to argue against, rather than honestly representing the real problem or the real arguments of your opponents. Over-simplification is one of the ways that you might make a straw man easy to defeat.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say that you don't want to make the argument *about* Richtman, that basically means you need to appeal to your audience directly. You can remind them of the parable of the [blind men and an elephant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_men_and_an_elephant). This parable reminds us that a report can be truthful and be made in good faith, but may utterly fail to capture the big picture, and may seemingly contradict other reports that are  truthful and made in good faith.

> It is a story of a group of blind men, who have never come across an elephant before and who learn and conceptualize what the elephant is like by touching it. Each blind man feels a different part of the elephant body, but only one part, such as the side or the tusk. They then describe the elephant based on their partial experience and their descriptions are in complete disagreement on what an elephant is. In some versions, they come to suspect that the other person is dishonest and they come to blows. The moral of the parable is that humans have a tendency to project their partial experiences as the whole truth, ignore other people's partial experiences, and one should consider that one may be partially right and may have partial information.
>
> [...]
>
> The parable has been used to illustrate a range of truths and
>   fallacies; broadly, the parable implies that one's subjective
>   experience can be true, but that such experience is inherently limited
>   by its failure to account for other truths or a totality of truth. At
>   various times the parable has provided insight into the relativism,
>   opaqueness or inexpressible nature of truth, the behavior of experts
>   in fields where there is a deficit or inaccessibility of information,
>   the need for communication, and respect for different perspectives.

Blind men and an elephant
From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia

Comment: Yes, exactly, ...  a report that is truthful, accurate in what it reports, and made in good  faith. I want to highlight it, not refute it. I'm not wanting to discredit the report, or make accusations of deception. I want to point out other angles, the bigger picture, which the report doesn't address. I'd not heard of the parable of the elephant before.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Having *tunnel vision*, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tunnel-vision) (emphasised *disapproving*, because it's how the word is used, not the definition):

> **disapproving** the fact that someone considers only one part of a problem or situation, or holds a single opinion rather than having a more general understanding

Example sentence by [McGraw-Hill Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tunnel+vision):

> The boss really has tunnel vision about sales and marketing. He sees no reason to change anything.

Attribution:

(Definition of “tunnel vision” from the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus © Cambridge University Press)

McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. S.v. "tunnel vision." Retrieved June 4 2018 from https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tunnel+vision

Answer (score 1):

To ***whitewash*** something is to present a tidied up version with superficially truthful facts while at the same time overlooking or covering up any disagreeable facts that might cause one to come to an other than optimistic conclusion.

From [Idioms by The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/whitewash):

> 1. (tv.) to make something look better than it really is; to conceal something bad. *Now, don’t try to whitewash this incident. Open up about it.*
> 2. (n.) an act or campaign of covering up something bad. *They  tried to give the scandal the old whitewash, but it didn’t work.*

*Whitewash* refers to an inexpensive paint made from slaked lime and chalk that is commonly associated with impoverished people (["Too proud to whitewash and too poor to paint". (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitewash#Usage_as_paint)). It becomes a metaphor for a hurried, slipshod or careless way of covering up when better materials and care would produce a more substantial result. One might say it's easier to whitewash something than to deal with all of the underlying issues that should be addressed.

Comment: "*whitewashing the elephant*" ? i found one usage of that phrase, in an anonymous comment: 
 http://theviewfromcullingworth.blogspot.com/2013/03/business-politics-why-heseltine-is-wrong.html

Answer (score 1):

This one admittedly *doesn't fit the example you've listed*, but just in case your actual context pertains more to a faulty argument for justifying the expenditure of money on something, this one shouldn't be ignored:

> ### penny-wise and pound-foolish
>
> to be extremely careful about small amounts of money and not careful enough about larger amounts of money
>   —[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/be-penny-wise-and-pound-foolish)
>
> So concerned with saving money in any way possible that one fails to allocate money to things that will ultimately force one to spend more (due to lack of quality, proper maintenance, etc).—[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/penny+wise+and+pound+foolish)

It doesn't necessarily imply deception, but *is* rather strong.

Comment: Thanks! +1. This is a good one, and it applies to some of my own (regrettable) personal budgetary decisions! (Just not quite the right fit for the idea I was trying to express.)