# What is the word that is used to describe the oversimplification or non-academic discussion of a complex issue?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word that is used to describe the oversimplification or non-academic discussion of a complex issue?

Typically, I'm looking for a word like *pedantic*, or *puerile*, except that the word covers the fact that the discussion is particularly non-academic. I know that such a word exists since I have used it before, but it has skipped my mind.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phrase to give a non-detailed answer/explanation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/451959/phrase-to-give-a-non-detailed-answer-explanation)

Comment: [What's a common phrase that means to put it simply though not 100% correctly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210275/whats-a-common-phrase-that-means-to-put-it-simply-though-not-100-correctly) ('in layman's terms: gloss') / [Word meaning something is technically accurate but overly simplistic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124742/word-meaning-something-is-technically-accurate-but-overly-simplistic/449093#449093) ('facile'). _Do I have to take this to Meta_? Why are close-votes peremptorily removed with no justification?

Comment: [please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests)

Comment: Have you looked at what I consider to be duplicates of this question? 'How to express a push for simplicity when explaining complex topics' (answers: dumbing down, KISS, plain language). // 'What is the word whose meaning is to oversimplify a complex issue often incorrectly?' (dumb down). // 'What's a common phrase that means to put it simply though not 100% correctly?' (in layman's terms; gloss) // Word meaning something is technically accurate but overly simplistic (facile; shallow; superficial). // Do they not answer your question?

Comment: oversimplification and non-academic are not equivalent terms, so there is no one word to correctly capture the meaning of both at the same time.

Comment: I propose that the proposed similar question that closed this one is not the same as what was being asked.  'Disengenious' implies a level of deception, purposely hiding true motives.  OP here was asking about an honest discussion that superficially covers the topic.

Comment: How could you think "pedantic" and "puerile" were comparable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I propose "Wetherspoonian".  e.g. *Brexit makes perfect economic sense on a Wetherspooonian level.*

Answer (score 29):

With regard to the context you have provided, you might want to consider the word "***facile***" -

> **Facile**
>
> 1. (especially of a theory or argument) appearing neat and
>    comprehensive only by ignoring the true complexities of an issue;
>    superficial.
> 2. Having or revealing a superficial or simplistic knowledge or approach: *a facile and shallow intellect*.

([From Oxford](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Vm_mNJiflwgC&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=facile+adj+(especially+of+a+theory+or+argument)+appearing+neat+and+comprehensive+only+by+ignoring+the+true+complexities+of+an+issue;+superficial&source=bl&ots=d2XZnPi8GT&sig=ACfU3U1kZySG2J1okIXIuJdCwtGhYZCbVA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiLsfrkjd_mAhUUX30KHcMwDVYQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=facile%20adj%20(especially%20of%20a%20theory%20or%20argument)%20appearing%20neat%20and%20comprehensive%20only%20by%20ignoring%20the%20true%20complexities%20of%20an%20issue%3B%20superficial&f=false))

Answer (score 17):

Depending on your desired connotation, you might consider:

## reductive

> : adj considering or presenting something in a simple way, especially a way that is too simple

[from Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/reductive)

The implication here is that the simplification is so great that key elements have been stripped away and what remains is no longer accurate.

Comment: This would be the word to use if lay people knew it.

Comment: @nomen, yeah, that's a fair observation

Answer (score 14):

From the definition of facile: "***superficial***" covers it pretty well.

> **2** 
>   **a**: concerned only with the obvious or apparent: SHALLOW
>
> **b**: seen on
>   the surface: EXTERNAL
>
> **c**: presenting only an appearance without
>   substance or significance

([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superficial))

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps you are looking for "in layman terms"

> (idiomatic) Phrased simply, without jargon. — [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_layman%27s_terms)

Comment: Also consider the adjective *lay*, as in "a lay discussion of a complex topic."  See definition 3 of 7 at https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lay:  "Belonging to, pertaining to, or performed by the people or *laity*, as distinguished from the clergy; not belonging to, connected with, or proceeding from a profession, especially the law or medicine."

Comment: Further back, *lay* is connected to the root \*leHd- which signifies something military, cp *luitenant*, should not be confused with Ger *Leute* "people", nor Dutch *lijfeigene* "serf", although a historic conflation about *loan* Ger *leih-*, cp. Danish *leje*, Fr *louer*, "Pg *alugar* "borrow, rent", has been considered in accademia for *leibeigen*; also cp Fr *loy* "law", Lat *lex, legem* (vs Ger *legen* "to lie, lay" in many ways), or *Leumunt* "good standing; judgement by peers" (thus cp *gossip*?). Last but not least, Proto Indo European society is deemed tripartite, at least.

Comment: At least, *layperson* is often understood as *amateur*. A distinction *practitionor* vs *theoretician* lends itself well to the comparison, as *layman* is traditionally used in terms of law, church law as it were, ironically as *user, applicant* in contradistinction to *practitioner* of law. Anyway its often understood to be *just* (the *rechtschaffender Bürger* "upright citizen", if *rechtskundiger Laihe* "knowledgable layperson" is not to be a contradiction in terms; I'm sorry that I am not well acquainted with the commonwealth jargon). So the pejorative is well ambiguous, almost metaphoric.

Answer (score 11):

## Dumbing it down

is a phrase that immediately came to mind to me - though not one word per se.

Answer (score 10):

Consider [shallow](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/shallow?s=t).

With respect to the context that you have cited, shallow, here, would mean - "not exhibiting, requiring, or capable of serious thought" — [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/shallow).

*Example sentence: A complex political issue was discussed in a **shallow** manner by the lower House of the Parliament.*

Answer (score 7):

I might use one of several adjective such as "**vague**", "**informal**", "**casual**", or "**simplistic**" to describe a discussion of superficial views, ideas, or concepts applied to a complex topic (depending on the specific occasion or intended emphasis).

> His interpretation was outrageous. Our informal discussions, just
>   casual discourses of the topic, became an arsenal of discrediting
>   views with his added academic detail.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/informal

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/simplistic

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/vague

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/casual

Answer (score 5):

How about "rudimentary", as in "My father has a rudimentary understanding of computers".

Definition of rudimentary:

> 1 : consisting in first principles : fundamental - "had only a rudimentary formal education" — D. J. Boorstin
>
> 2 : of a primitive kind - "the equipment of these past empire-builders was rudimentary" — A. J. Toynbee

from [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rudimentary)

Note that "elementary" could also fit.

Answer (score 3):

**Armchair**, as in:

> Armchair Philosophy

or

> Armchair Climate Science

When I saw the title of the question, this seemed to fit perfectly. I also didn't see it posted anywhere here, so I'll mention it in case it is the word that you remember.

Comment: I like this a lot.  A similar term would be “bro science”, as in, “My running coach says I need to eat more carrots so I can see better when running track, but I think that’s just bro science.”

Answer (score 1):

A high level overview? If looking for a business term.

> High-level means "general" or "big picture." [...] A "high-level overview" is one that doesn't cover details. It provides a very basic and general explanation or presentation of the material/subject.
>
> ([wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/high-level.814580/))

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd go with 'in layman's terms' as suggested above but if you need a single word then **exoteric** might work, which means suitable for the general public and is the opposite of esoteric which means likely to only be understood by a small group of people with specialized knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Unprofessional review?

[Unprofessional](https://www.lexico.com/definition/unprofessional)

> Below or contrary to the standards expected in a particular
> profession.

Therefore you need to get in quick while they are offering a professional service for an unprofessional fee.

Examples -

> "*One of the main pitfalls is picking a development partner who is
> inexperienced and unprofessional.*"
>
> "*Complaints are mounting about the
> unprofessional job the contractors are doing.*"